# @RequestBody and custom org.springframework.validation.Validator

Tags: ajax, json, spring, spring-validator

I have controller that recieve json object like this: `"fields" : ["abc","one","two","three"]`

```
@RequestMapping(value="submit.controller", produces="application/json",
        consumes="application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public View submit(@RequestBody Form form) {
    // populating view;
    return view;
}
```

And the following form:

```
public class Form {

    private List<String> fields;

    public List<String> getFields(){
        return fields;
    }

    public setFields(List<String> fields){
        this.fields= fields;
    }
}
```

And validator:

```
public class CustomValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Form.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        Form form = (Form) target;
        // some complexity validation
    }

}
```

And handler:

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public String handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(
        MethodArgumentNotValidException error) {
    return error.getBindingResult();
}
```

My goal is to validate `Form` via my custom validator without using annotation @Valid, such as it doesn't work in my case(**Adding of `<mvc:annotation-driven />` require a lot of refactoring**).

How can it should be implemented without **BindingResult** in controller?

Comment: I'm confused. Your MVC classes are annotation driven but you're saying `<mvc:annotation-driven />` requires a lot of refactoring?

Comment: All controllers mapping are registered in servletmvc-servlet.xml via <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">

Comment: Also we have <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver" p:order="1" /> for annotations